# How performant is CIFilter for displaying several grayscale images in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cifilter

I am using the following to convert images to grayscale before showing them on a UITableView using UIImageView:

```
extension UIImage {
    var noir: UIImage? {
        let contextForGrayscale = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir") else { return nil }
        currentFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: self), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        if let output = currentFilter.outputImage,
            let cgImage = contextForGrayscale.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Since I am showing these images in a UITableView using UIImageView, each image is being grayscaled as the user scrolls. On my iPhone 13, the performance seems very good and I don't see any lag. However, I am curious how good its performance is on an old device. I don't have an old device, so I am unable to test it.

1. Is this a performant way to grayscale on the fly and display them? Is there anything I can do to make it better?
2. Is there a way to make my phone slower for testing the performance? Sort of like simulate older device?

Answer (score 1):

If performance / memory pressure doesn't seem to be an issue, I'd just not worry about it. If it is a problem you could use `NSCache`.

I'd do the caching outside the extension, but for the sake of the code example:

```
extension UIImage {
    
    private static var noirCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    
    func makeNoirImage(identifier: String) -> UIImage? {
        if let cachedImage = UIImage.noirCache.object(forKey: identifier as NSString) {
          return cachedImage
        }
        
        let contextForGrayscale = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir") else { return nil }
        currentFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: self), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        if let output = currentFilter.outputImage,
            let cgImage = contextForGrayscale.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
            
            let noirImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
            UIImage.noirCache.setObject(noirImage, forKey: identifier as NSString)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Also, check out this article https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/
You could, in addition to creating this new image, also create a thumbnail right sized for its display image view and use the built in caching mechanisms for this. This would save some memory and performance overall. But again, if it's not an issue, I'd be happier to just have the simpler code and no caching!

Oh, one more thing. You could use this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching to create the image ahead of time async before the cell is displayed, so it's ready to go by the time the table asks for the cell for the given index path. Thinking about it this is probably the simplest / nicest solution here.

Comment: Also, don't create a new `CIContext` for each image! It's a very expensive object that does a lot of internal caching, so you should only create one and re-use it for every image (which would make rendering consecutive images even faster).

Comment: @Andrew Carter Unfortunately, I don't know if the performance is an issue or not on older devices as I don't have access to older devices. Is there a way to simulate an older device performance on newer devices? Similar to how we have slow network simulator settings in iPhone?